# How to create child canvas inside parent canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I have main canvas

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=512, height=512)
canvas.pack()
```

And for example class-canvas with some objects inside:

```
class My_object(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.create_line(0,0, 100, 100)
        self.create_oval(0,0, 100, 100)
```

I would like to add examples of My_object to my main canvas with certain coordinates. How to do it?
If i make this:

```
obj = My_object(canvas)
obj.pack()
```

then this new object replaces my main canvas

Comment: Could you explain better this: "I would like to add examples of My_object to my main canvas with certain coordinates." and this: "then this new object replaces my main canvas". For me it's not so clear, but maybe it's just me. Edit your question with a better explanation.

Comment: Let i have class, which is represented by canvas with little painted car. I want to add this car to my main canvas like a rectangle or other objects like: main_canvas.create_rectangle(...) <=> main_canvas.create_car(..)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the interior canvas (or any other widget) to be part of the canvas (ie: scroll along with the lines and other objects), use the [create_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) method of the canvas.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=512, height=512)
canvas.pack()
...
child_canvas = My_object(canvas)
canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=child_canvas)
```

Note that embedded widgets will always have a z-axis higher than any drawn items. In other words, it will always appear on top of any lines, rectangles, etc.

Comment: Do you know what happens if we give the master to be the canvas? Like: `Label(canvas, ...)` and not use `create_window` but instead `pack`/`grid`, will the label be inside the canvas? or the root window

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria: the label will be inside the canvas borders, but it will not scroll.